# SQL Sort population by value and place in groups by value

Tags: sql

I have to create a report. I’m having trouble figuring how to approach it. On top of that, I don’t have the proper vocabulary to express it, and thusly search for the solution. Please bear with me.

I have a population of accounts. The accounts must be ordered by value. The accounts at bottom 5% of the overall value are placed in a group (Group #5). The remaining 95% of the population are divided into four equal groups (Groups #1-4) by value (not by number of accounts).

The values of the accounts change over time so the results would change over time. I'm hoping to produce an output something like this...

> ```
> ACC#  |VALUE|GROUP|
> ------+-----+-----+
> 2615A | 24  | 1
> 0793A | 24  | 2
> 0652A | 12  | 3
> 6758A | 12  | 3
> 7764A |  6  | 4
> 8718A |  6  | 4
> 0155A |  6  | 4
> 6923A |  5  | 4
> 8079A |  3  | 5
> 2265A |  1  | 5
> 7421A |  1  | 5
> ```

I have the option of running it in SQL Server or Oracle(11g). Whichever gets me over the finish line. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Option huh. Which version of MS Sql Server?

Comment: Assigning Group 5 is easy with a percentile function. What the rule for the other grouping? Is it by groups of 25ths? Like 6-25th, 26-50,51-75,76-100

Comment: Maybe there's a voodoo way to do this, but offhand I see a fairly straightforward *program.*  First you'd need to query your table and `ORDER BY VALUE`.  Then, by some means, you'd need to determine where the group-boundaries lie for each group, for *this* particular set of data.  Finally, you'd need to execute an `UPDATE` query to populate `GROUP`.  (Now, you *could* construct that query to use `IF` or `CASE` constructs ...)

Comment: 11.0.6 on MSSSM 2014

Comment: The grouping would be such that the sum value for the top 23.75% (0.25 * 95%)  of the overall value of the population falls into group 1. the next 23.75% of value into group 2, so on and so forth. Naturally there would be more accounts in the lower end of the spectrum needed to get to the 24%. Fewer accounts at the top group since each account has more value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `row_number()` and `count()` window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum <= (cnt * 0.95 * 0.25) then 1
             when seqnum <= (cnt * 0.95 * 0.50) then 2
             when seqnum <= (cnt * 0.95 * 0.75) then 3
             when seqnum <= (cnt * 0.95 * 1.00) then 4
             else 5
        end) as grp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by value desc, acc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note:  rows with the same value can be in different groups -- as in your example data.  If you don't want this to be the case, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

EDIT:

If you want equal value, just use cumulative sums and totals:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_value <= (total_value * 0.95 * 0.25) then 1
             when running_value <= (total_value * 0.95 * 0.50) then 2
             when running_value <= (total_value * 0.95 * 0.75) then 3
             when running_value <= (total_value * 0.95 * 1.00) then 4
             else 5
        end) as grp
from (select t.*,
             sum(value) over (order by value desc, acc) as running_value,
             sum(value) over () as total_value
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Yes, this might be an example of the "SQL voodoo" that I spoke of in my previous comment, which might indeed do exactly what you need.  (I'm not intending to comment *about* this solution ...)  But it also is an illustration of the use of `case..when`, if you wind up building some program instead.

Comment: @Greg_D . . . Lest you be "spooked" by Mike's comment, there is no "voodoo" in this answer at all.  It is using standard window functions and rather simple comparisons in a `case` expression.

Comment: Thanks. This divides into equal parts by number of accounts. My assignment is to divide into groups of equal value. If the total value of the population is 1000, I'd have to add ordered accounts until it equals 237+/- (23.75% of 1000).

Comment: @Greg_D . . . Exactly the same idea with running sums.

Comment: Great! Thanks. This solution produced more equal values and groups with the live data set than the solution provided by Luz (also a great solution). I assume it has more to do with how the sorting was originally declared more than anything. Going to dissect the COALESCE vs RUNNING SUM some more.

Answer (score 1):

Using a few SUM OVER's seems to get those results somehow.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test
> (
>   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>   ACC# VARCHAR(5),
>   [VALUE] INT
> );
> INSERT INTO test 
> (ACC#, [VALUE]) VALUES
> ('2615A', 24),
> ('0793A', 24),
> ('0652A', 12),
> ('6758A', 12),
> ('7764A',  6),
> ('8718A',  6),
> ('0155A',  6),
> ('6923A',  5),
> ('8079A',  3),
> ('2265A',  1),
> ('7421A',  1);
> >
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE_DATA AS
> (
>   SELECT *,
>   CASE 
>   WHEN (1.0*SUM([VALUE]) OVER (ORDER BY [VALUE], ID DESC)
>           / SUM([VALUE]) OVER ()) <= 0.05
>   THEN 5
>   END AS grp
>   FROM test
> )
> SELECT ID, ACC#, [VALUE],
>  COALESCE(grp
>      , CEILING(FLOOR(
>        100.0*SUM([VALUE]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY [VALUE] DESC, ID) 
>            / SUM([VALUE]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
>        )/25)
>     ) AS [GROUP]
> FROM CTE_DATA
> ORDER BY ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | ACC#  | VALUE | GROUP
> -: | :---- | ----: | :----
>  1 | 2615A |    24 | 1    
>  2 | 0793A |    24 | 2    
>  3 | 0652A |    12 | 3    
>  4 | 6758A |    12 | 3    
>  5 | 7764A |     6 | 4    
>  6 | 8718A |     6 | 4    
>  7 | 0155A |     6 | 4    
>  8 | 6923A |     5 | 4    
>  9 | 8079A |     3 | 5    
> 10 | 2265A |     1 | 5    
> 11 | 7421A |     1 | 5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ab79a43c043eb37d0f24266634513da7)*

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks Luk!

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for the puzzle also.  Made me rediscover & experiment with functions like [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql), [CUME_DIST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cume-dist-transact-sql) , [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql) or [PERCENT_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql).  But in the end I still ended up with using a cumulative sum.  o_O